# When sending AWS SES emails using a node serverless lamda environment, an endpoint request timeout error can occur

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

When sending AWS SES emails using a node serverless lamda environment, an endpoint request timeout error can occur
When I run this code locally it's working fine but when I upload code in lamda and try to run function it throw "Endpoint request timed out" error

below is my code for sending emails :

```
    'use strict';
    const API = require('../helper/API_Responce');
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        region: 'us-east-2'
    });

module.exports.myAPIs = async (event) => {
    switch (event.pathParameters) {
        case "send_test_email":
            try {
                const input = JSON.parse(event.body);
                let my_link = "Testing email";
                var data = {
                    to: "test@gmail.com",
                    text: my_link,
                    subject: "test",
                }
                let res = sendMails(data)
                return API._200(await res);
            } catch (ex) {
                return API._400(ex);
            }
            break;

        default:
            return API._400([{ message: "Recheck url please." }]);
            break;
    }
}
async function sendMails(data) {
    const params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [data.to],
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Html: {
                    Charset: 'UTF-8',
                    Data: data.text,
                },
            },
            Subject: { Charset: 'UTF-8', Data: data.subject },
        },
        Source: '*******',
    };
    const SES1 = new AWS.SES({ region: "us-east-1" });
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await SES1.sendEmail(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                resolve([{ message: err.message, StatusCode: 0 }])
            } else {
                resolve([{ message: "Mail Send Successfully", StatusCode: 1 }])
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand: the timeout occurs all the time deploying the code in Lambda, or only sometimes?

Comment: got this error every time while call this Api

Comment: This might be a permissions issue. When you run the code on your local machine it's using your (probably administrator-like) IAM role which has access to SES. When you are running in Lambda it's using a different role which doesn't have sufficient permissions. Sometimes when you don't have sufficient permissions it causes a timeout. Another possible explanation is that there is no path from your Lambda to the SES endpoint. Is there a VPCE for your Lambda which connects your Lambda to SES? That might solve the problem. Alternatively, put the Lambda into a public subnet.